# Ruby: failed to make a successful GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am trying to send a http.get request to different websites. Here is the code I am using:

```
def makePing
   begin 
      url = URI.parse(@URI)
      req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
      res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
          http.read_timeout = @request_timeout_limit
          http.request(req)
       }
       # debugger      
   rescue Exception => echo

     puts "Error is: Failed to open TCP connection to #{@URI}"
   end 
end
```

It returns the result of 200 for `'http://www.example.com'`
but
for `http://www.google.com` or `http://www.facebook.com`
it returns

```
<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true>
```

1-I am wondering why it happens like this?

2-How can I get the body of the response?

3- I expect that, the request get expired exactly after `@request_timeout_limit`, and it stop trying, but it is not working in this way?

Comment: @João Silva .........

Comment: I have just copy pasted your code to a ruby console and I got <Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true>  for @URI = "http://www.google.com"